Where is subscription usage data stored in WSO2 API Manager (v4.2)?
I've configured rate limiting in WSO2 API Manager v4.2 and subscribed to APIs. However, I'm struggling to locate where the subscriber usage data is stored within the API Manager!
Specifically:

Storage Location: Where is the subscriber usage data (e.g., request counts per user, per API, per subscription) stored? I've checked the database for subscription-related tables but couldn't find usage data.
Usage Retrieval: How can I effectively identify which users have accessed specific resources and the number of requests they've made within the rate limits?

Additionally, upon restarting the API Manager, the expected rate-limiting behavior (e.g., receiving an error after exceeding the limit) does not persist. This suggests that usage data might not be persistently stored.
Any advice on querying relevant tables, event stores, or analytics within WSO2 API Manager would be greatly appreciated.

These are not stored in the DB unless you enable API analytics. To enable Analytics with ELK please refer to this document.
